# Zip all iso files in current directory and move zip file to another directory

Tags: linux, debian, zip, iso

I am trying to zip all .iso files into a single zip file. Then move the zip file to another directory. Some of the iso files have very long names. How can I zip ALL iso files, without having to type or tab them into a long command?

```
zip myisos.zip amd64.iso i386.iso

sudo mv myisos.zip /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/
```

Comment: Try `zip myisos.zip *.isos`.

Comment: @berndbausch: You have an extra 's' as the end. It should be `zip myisos.zip \*.iso` . As a side note to the OP: As long as you have write permissions on the destination directory, you can skip the `mv` command by specifying the full path and file name: `zip /opt/bitnami/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-content/myisos.zip *.iso` . You can do similar with the '\*.iso' part. For example, if your iso files are in `/home/sigur7/isofiles`, change the '\*.iso' to '/home/sigur7/isofiles/\*.iso' .